Split a polars DataFrame into multiple chunks with groupby
Consider the following pl.DataFrames:
import datetime

import polars as pl

df_orig = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": [*["A"] * 10, *["B"] * 8],
        "date": [
            *pl.datetime_range(
                start=datetime.date(2024, 1, 1),
                end=datetime.date(2024, 1, 10),
                eager=True,
            ),
            *pl.datetime_range(
                start=datetime.date(2024, 1, 1),
                end=datetime.date(2024, 1, 8),
                eager=True,
            ),
        ],
        "data": [*range(10), *range(8)],
    }
)

df_helper = pl.DataFrame({"symbol": ["A", "B"], "start_idx": [[0, 5], [0, 4]]})

chunk_size = 5

with pl.Config(tbl_rows=30):
    print(df_orig)
    print(df_helper)


shape: (18, 3)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ symbol ┆ date                ┆ data │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 8    │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 9    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘

shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ symbol ┆ start_idx │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ A      ┆ [0, 5]    │
│ B      ┆ [0, 3]    │
└────────┴───────────┘

Now, I need to split the dataframe into two chunks of length 5 (chunk_size) grouped by the symbol column. The column start_idx indicate the rows to start the chunk in each group. That is, group A will be split into two chunks of length 5 starting in row 0 and 5, while the chunks of grouß B start in row 0 and 3.
Finally, all chunks need to be concatenated on axis=0, whereby a new column split_idx indicates where the split is coming from.
Here's what I am looking for:
shape: (20, 4)
┌────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ split_idx ┆ symbol ┆ date                ┆ data │
│           ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ i64       ┆ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞═══════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 0         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ 0         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ 0         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ 0         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ 0         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ 0         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ 0         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ 0         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ 0         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ 0         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ 1         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ 1         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ 1         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
│ 1         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 8    │
│ 1         ┆ A      ┆ 2024-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 9    │
│ 1         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ 1         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ 1         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ 1         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ 1         ┆ B      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
└───────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘

Keep in mind that list in column start_idx may be of variable length for each individual row. The length of each list determines the number of chunks for each group.

Are you sure the expected output is correct? Specifically the date column for the second half.

You're right. I corrected the date column in the expected dataframe.

I think it's still wrong - the 5th last row starts from index 3 and not 4.

You're correct again. However, I corrected the start_idx list in df_helper. That's where the error is.

Here is a solution that fully stays within the polars expression API.
The primary idea is to preprocess the helper dataframe into a dataframe of symbol, split_idx, and row_idx. Here, row_idx is the index of a row within a group defined by symbol and split index.
It can serve as a "skeleton" and we can (after adding such a row index to df_orig) easily use it for a left-merge with df_orig.
pl.Config().set_tbl_rows(-1)

def preprocess_helper(df_helper: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return (
        df_helper
        .explode("start_idx")
        .with_columns(
            pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("symbol").alias("split_idx"),
            pl.int_ranges(pl.col("start_idx"), pl.col("start_idx") + chunk_size).alias("row_idx"),
        )
        .explode("row_idx")
    )

(
    preprocess_helper(df_helper)
    .join(
        df_orig.with_columns(pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("symbol").alias("row_idx")),
        on=["symbol", "row_idx"],
        how="left",
    )
    .drop("row_idx", "start_idx")
    .sort("split_idx", "symbol")
)

Note. The final pl.DataFrame.drop / pl.DataFrame.sort can be omitted if the exact columns / order of the output does not matter.
shape: (20, 4)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ symbol ┆ split_idx ┆ date                ┆ data │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ i64       ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ A      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ A      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ A      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ A      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ A      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ B      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    │
│ B      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ B      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
│ B      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ B      ┆ 0         ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ A      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ A      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ A      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
│ A      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 8    │
│ A      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 9    │
│ B      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    │
│ B      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    │
│ B      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    │
│ B      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    │
│ B      ┆ 1         ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    │
└────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘


This is a pretty neat solution. I stumbled a bit over chunk_idx. The name is basically interchangable with split_idx, so it's a bit confusing what this is about.

@Andi Glad it helped. You are right, the name as ambiguous. Maybe row_idx would be a better name. I've adapted the name accordingly.

I could not come up with a fully native solution since polars.Expr.slice does not seem to support different values for each row.
Here's one way to do this with some Python code mixed in:
First, group df_orig by symbol and put it in a dict.
Then, iterate over df_helper and extract the slices and put them in a list.
Finally, concat the dataframes into a single dataframe and sort it.
df_orig_by_symbol = {
    k: v for ((k,), v) in df_orig.group_by("symbol", maintain_order=True)
}

dfs = []

for symbol, start_idxs in df_helper.select("symbol", "start_idx").iter_rows():
    for split_idx, start_idx in enumerate(start_idxs):
        dfs.append(
            df_orig_by_symbol[symbol]
            .slice(start_idx, chunk_size)
            .with_columns(split_idx=split_idx)
        )

final_df = pl.concat(dfs).sort("split_idx", "symbol")

Output:
shape: (20, 4)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ symbol ┆ date                ┆ data ┆ split_idx │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  ┆ i32       │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ 0         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ 0         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    ┆ 0         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    ┆ 0         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    ┆ 0         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0    ┆ 0         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    ┆ 0         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    ┆ 0         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    ┆ 0         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    ┆ 0         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    ┆ 1         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    ┆ 1         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    ┆ 1         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-09 00:00:00 ┆ 8    ┆ 1         │
│ A      ┆ 2024-01-10 00:00:00 ┆ 9    ┆ 1         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 3    ┆ 1         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-05 00:00:00 ┆ 4    ┆ 1         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-06 00:00:00 ┆ 5    ┆ 1         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-07 00:00:00 ┆ 6    ┆ 1         │
│ B      ┆ 2024-01-08 00:00:00 ┆ 7    ┆ 1         │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┴───────────┘

Full code:
import datetime

import polars as pl

df_orig = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": [*["A"] * 10, *["B"] * 8],
        "date": [
            *pl.datetime_range(
                start=datetime.date(2024, 1, 1),
                end=datetime.date(2024, 1, 10),
                eager=True,
            ),
            *pl.datetime_range(
                start=datetime.date(2024, 1, 1),
                end=datetime.date(2024, 1, 8),
                eager=True,
            ),
        ],
        "data": [*range(10), *range(8)],
    }
)

df_helper = pl.DataFrame({"symbol": ["A", "B"], "start_idx": [[0, 5], [0, 3]]})


chunk_size = 5

df_orig_by_symbol = {
    k: v for ((k,), v) in df_orig.group_by("symbol", maintain_order=True)
}

dfs = []

for symbol, start_idxs in df_helper.select("symbol", "start_idx").iter_rows():
    for split_idx, start_idx in enumerate(start_idxs):
        dfs.append(
            df_orig_by_symbol[symbol]
            .slice(start_idx, chunk_size)
            .with_columns(split_idx=split_idx)
        )

final_df = pl.concat(dfs).sort("split_idx", "symbol")

with pl.Config(tbl_rows=100):
    print(final_df)

